# Is possible to use dependency injection in a Powershell Binary Module?

Tags: c#, powershell, dependency-injection

I am writing a Binary PowerShell Module (in .net 6), it's possible to implement dependency injection in this use case? If yes, how?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give an example?

Comment: Dependency injection _into what_?

Comment: DI with in PowerShell Binary Module aka C# PowerShell Module